# jQuery UI modal dialog blocks clicking event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have a problem with clicking button to display popup.

In my layout.jspx, I have following:

```
        <div class="menuBtn">
            <div class="search">
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
</div>      

<!-- USERINFO POPUP -->
<div class="popup accDetail user" id="userPopup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="userInfo">
        <img src="${img_user}" width="60" height="60"></img>
        <div>
            <p class="department"><security:authentication property="securityUser.department"/></p>
            <p class="name"><security:authentication property="securityUser.userName"/></p>
            <p class="email"><security:authentication property="securityUser.email"/></p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn clear cen floatNone">
            <a class='blank' href="${url_logout}">Log Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks icon, it will display userPopup.

It actually works well in other page. (On top-right side of the page)

[image]

Then in one of my jsp, I do have following:

HTML

```
<div class="mainarea">
    <div class="dataTitle">
        <h2 class='h2Title'>Annual Leave</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="searchParentOne">
        <div>
            <input type="image" class="addNewLetter" src="/ias/resources/images/leave.png" 
            style="height:128px;width:256px;">
            <p class="temp-test" style="display:none;"><security:authentication property='securityUser.fullName'/></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="popup accDetail" id="letterDialog" title="Leave Application" style="display: none;">
<div class="popupmainarea">
    <div class="clear bttn" id="divSmallDate">
        <div class="bttn rig floatNone">
            <button type="button" class="ui-lngbutton edit_ui selectLine">Line</button>
            <button type="button" class="ui-button up_ui btnSendDoc" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="ui-button cancel_ui btnCancelCon">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form id="formAddNewDoc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="data">
        <div>
            <p align="center"><font size="6">Annual Leave</font></p>
        </div>

        <table class="custbltwo">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 40%;">
                <col style="width: 60%;">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead">Document No.</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="border-style: solid hidden solid solid;"><p id="documentId">Mobile C&C Cambodia-XX-XXXX</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead">Department</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="border-style: solid hidden solid solid;"><p></p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="docDepartment" id="docDepartment"/>
                    </td>               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead">Approval Date</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="border-style: solid hidden solid solid;"><p id="docDisplayDate" class="today"></p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="docHideCDate" id="docHideCDate"/>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead">Writer</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="border-style: solid hidden solid solid;">
                    <p class="temp-test">
                    <security:authentication property='securityUser.fullName'/>
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="docEmployee" id="docEmployee" value="<security:authentication property="securityUser.fullName"/>"/>
                    </td>               
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="custblthree">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 12%;">
                <col style="width: 17.6%;">
                <col style="width: 17.6%;">
                <col style="width: 17.6%;">
                <col style="width: 17.6%;">
                <col style="width: 17.6%;">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Approval<strong class="required">*</strong>
                    <input type="hidden" name="docApproval" id="docApproval">
                    </td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick1"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docApp0" id="docApp0" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick2"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docApp1" id="docApp1" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick3"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docApp2" id="docApp2" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick4"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docApp3" id="docApp3" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick5"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docApp4" id="docApp4" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick6"><img id="docAppNumImg0"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick7"><img id="docAppNumImg1"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick8"><img id="docAppNumImg2"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick9"><img id="docAppNumImg3"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick10"><img id="docAppNumImg4"></img>
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAppNum0" id="docAppNum0" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAppNum1" id="docAppNum1" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAppNum2" id="docAppNum2" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAppNum3" id="docAppNum3" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAppNum4" id="docAppNum4" value="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead" rowspan="2">Agreement
                    <input type="hidden" name="docSettlement[]" id="docSettlement">
                    </td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick11"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docAgg0" id="docAgg0" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick12"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docAgg1" id="docAgg1" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick13"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docAgg2" id="docAgg2" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick14"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docAgg3" id="docAgg3" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" align="center" id="clickclick15"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docAgg4" id="docAgg4" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick16"><img id="docAggNumImg0"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick17"><img id="docAggNumImg1"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick18"><img id="docAggNumImg2"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick19"><img id="docAggNumImg3"></img></td>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" align="center" id="clickclick20"><img id="docAggNumImg4"></img>
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAggNum0" id="docAggNum0" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAggNum1" id="docAggNum1" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAggNum2" id="docAggNum2" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAggNum3" id="docAggNum3" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="docAggNum4" id="docAggNum4" value="0">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="custbleone">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 10.8%;">
                <col style="width: 14.5%;">
                <col style="width: 4%;">
                <col style="width: 14.5%;">
                <col style="width: 56.2%;">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">Reference</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" id="clickclick21" colspan="4" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docReference[]" id="docReference" placeholder="Reference"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead">Implement<strong class="required">*</strong></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" colspan="4" valign="middle">
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="docEnforcement" id="docEnforcement" style="border:0;"value="<security:authentication property="securityUser.fullName"/>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead">Period<strong class="required">*</strong></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: solid hidden solid solid;"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" class='ihalf dateOne' id="sDate" name="sDate" 
                    placeholder="2016-01-01" style="display:inline;"><input type="hidden" name="docStartDate" id="docStartDate"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="border-style: solid hidden solid hidden;"><p class="ptilde" style="display:inline;">&nbsp&nbsp~</p></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: solid hidden solid hidden;"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" class='ihalf dateTwo' id="eDate" name="eDate" placeholder="2016-01-01" style="display:inline;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="docEndDate" id="docEndDate"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="border-style: solid solid solid hidden;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbHead" style="border-style: solid solid hidden solid;">Title<strong class="required">*</strong></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" colspan="4" style="border-style: solid solid hidden solid;"><input type="text" id="docTitle" name="docTitle" placeholder="Title" maxlength="80"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="custbleone">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 20%;">
                <col style="width: 20%;">
                <col style="width: 20%;">
                <col style="width: 20%;">
                <col style="width: 20%;">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;">Annual Info Year</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;">Total Annual Leave</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;">Used Annual Leave</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;">Remain Annual Leave</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" style="text-align:center;">Request Annual Leave<strong class="required">*</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContent"><input type="number" readonly="readonly" name="docAnnualYear" id="docAnnualYear" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent"><input type="number" readonly="readonly" id="docTotalLeave" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent"><input type="number" readonly="readonly" id="docUsedLeave" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent"><input type="number" readonly="readonly" name="docRemainLeave" id="docRemainLeave" style="border:0; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td class="tbContent"><input type="number" name="docRequestLeave" id="docRequestLeave" step="0.5" style="text-align:center;"></td>
                    <!-- step attribute does not work -->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="custbleone">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContentTwo" valign="top" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">
                    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="docText" name="docText"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="custbleone">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 10%;">
                <col style="width: 10%;">
                <col style="width: 70%;">
                <col style="width: 10%;">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContent" rowspan="3" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">
                    Attachment</td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">
                        <input type="file" id="docFile1" name="docFile1" size="50" style="width:85px;"/></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="test1" class="test1" style="border:0;"/></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
                        <button type="button" id="clearDocFile1" style="display:none;">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid hidden solid;">
                        <input type="file" id="docFile2" name="docFile2" size="50" style="display:none; width:85px;"/></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="test2" class="test2" style="border:0;"/></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
                        <button type="button" id="clearDocFile2" style="display:none;">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid solid;">
                    <input type="file" id="docFile3" name="docFile3" size="50" style="display:none; width:85px;"/></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="test3" class="test3" style="border:0;"/></td>
                    <td class="tbContent" valign="middle" style="border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;">
                        <button type="button" id="clearDocFile3" style="display:none;">Delete</button></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="currentUser" id="currentUser" value="<security:authentication property="securityUser.fullName"/>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="docDisplayAllSum[]" id="docDisplayAllSet">
        <input type="hidden" name="docDisplayApp[]" id="docDisplayApp">
        <input type="hidden" name="docDisplaySet[]" id="docDisplaySet">
        <input type="hidden" name="docDisplayAllApp[]" id="docDisplayAllApp">
        <input type="hidden" name="docSum[]" id="docSum">
        <input type="hidden" name="docDisplayAllSum[]" id="docDisplayAllSum">
        <input type="hidden" name="docDisplaySum[]" id="docDisplaySum">
        <input type="hidden" name="docAgreeType[]" id="docAgreeType">
        <input type="hidden" value="Annual Leave" id="docType" name="docType"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="docAttachment" name="docAttachment"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="docDone" name="docDone"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="Report" id="docStatus" name="docStatus"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="false" id="docRejected" name="docRejected"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="fileName1" id="fileName1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="fileName2" id="fileName2"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="fileName3" id="fileName3"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".addNewLetter").on("click",function(e){
    $("#letterDialog").dialog("open");
    $(".floatNone :button").blur();
    $('.today').text(parseDatetoString(new Date(),CONSTANT.YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFORMAT));

    var currrentRemain = parseFloat($("#docRemainLeave").val());
    if (currrentRemain <= 0) {
        $(".btnSendDoc").hide();
    } else {
        $(".btnSendDoc").show();
    }

    $("#formAddNewDoc").validate({
        onclick : false,
        ignore : [],
        onkeyup : function(element) {
            return true;
        },
        onfocus : true,
        rules : {
            docTitle : {required : true, maxlength : 80},
            docStartDate : {required : true},
            docEndDate : {required : true},
            docApproval : {required : true},
            docEnforcement : {required : true},
            docRequestLeave : {required : true, min: 0.5, max: currrentRemain}
        },
        invalidHandler : function(e, validator) {
            if (!validator.numberOfInvalids()) {
                return;
            }
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top -30
            }, 1000, function(){
                $(validator.errorList[0].element).focus();
            });
        }
    });
});

initDialog : function(){
    $( "#letterDialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width : 1000,
        resizable: false,
        close: function( event, ui ) {
              $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
}
```

In following page, if I click leave application icon, the annual leave popup shows up.
[image]

[image]

However, when I click a profile icon on top-right side, userPopup does not show up.

It looks like the clicking event does not fire because of jQuery UI modal dialog.

How should I fix this?

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985992/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-blocking-click-event), but I am not sure if setTimeout is right, proper method to use.

Please give me some advice.

**EDIT**:

Forgot to show initDialog so I just add it under JavaScript part.

I made modal option as false, but it only removes modal, but that icon is still does not fire when I click it.

Comment: This behaviour can occur when the click event is triggered an even number of times. Have you duplicated the click handler? You can try if that is the case simply by using unbind() like in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understnad well enough.
Seems the popup shows up by code  `$("#letterDialog").dialog("open");`  is a modal dialog.

Have you try to set the modal option to false to re-try?

Like below code:
`$("#letterDialog").dialog('option', 'modal', false).dialog("open")`

Comment: Well, I did.  And still nothing happens when I click that userPopup icon.  Maybe it is not jQuery UI modal issue.

Comment: If you can move demo code to jsfiddle.com or something like that, that would help.